# How to export a variable which is in a class in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodejs-server

This is my file loginHandler.js

```
class LoginHandler {
 merchantId = '';
    returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
      merchantId = req.params.merchantId;
    }  
}

module.exports = new LoginHandler();
```

I want to access the variable `merchantId` on another file

```
const loginHandler  = require('./loginHandler')
class ResponseHandler {
    
    getResponseFromCOMM(options,token, res){
        console.log(loginHandler.merchantId)
    }
}
```

But merchantId is undefined. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here you can see the code on Glitch = https://glitch.com/edit/#!/turquoise-spiky-chrysanthemum

Comment: It works on my side, you can try as well `console.log(loginHandler)` to see the full object

Comment: It is because your merchantId is an empty string. Try with something like ```merchantId= 'default'```

Comment: But it's value is set inside the function returnURLForIframe

Comment: No, it is not set now, because you are using an instance of a class you need to change your code to ```this.merchantId = req.params.merchantId```

Comment: @Karlan If I do that, I get this error `Error is  TypeError: Cannot set property 'merchantId' of undefined `

Comment: I don't know the context of your code but it works for me. See my answer.

Comment: @Karlan `req.params` have nothing to do with this class. @NehalJaisalmeria your need to instantiate the class using the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Konowy check this `module.exports = new LoginHandler();`

Comment: I've seen @Karlan's answer and it's ok, but this comment with `req.params` was wrong,

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria Can you paste the full error when you do `console.log(loginHandler)`?

Comment: still working on my side. What's the error text?

Comment: @malarres `Error is  ReferenceError: merchantId is not defined                                                                           at returnURLForIframe (C:\Users\Acer\angularProjects\pamSetup\comm-channel-node-gateway\handler\loginHandler.js:8:18) `

Comment: How do you call returnURLForIframe?

Comment: `const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router()`

`router.get('^/:userId/:userType/:sessId/:lang/:orgId/:merchantId/:domainId', loginHandler.returnURLForIframe)`

Comment: ok i got it, you needed a `this`. See answer below

Comment: After adding `this` I'm getting `Error is  TypeError: Cannot set property 'merchantId' of undefined at returnURLForIframe (C:\Users\Acer\angularProjects\pamSetup\comm-channel-node-gateway\handler\loginHandler.js:10:23`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding it to an environment variable on loginHandler.js

`process.env.MERCHANT_ID = req.params.merchantId`

and then on responseHandler.js, I accessed that variable

`merchantId : process.env.MERCHANT_ID`

Answer (score 1):

My loginhanderler.js

```
class LoginHandler {
  merchantId = '';
  returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
    this.merchantId = req.params.merchantId;
  }
}

module.exports = new LoginHandler();
```

My index.js

```
let loginHandler = require('./loginhandler');

let req = {
  params: {
    merchantId: 'a test',
  },
};

loginHandler.returnURLForIframe(req);

console.log(loginHandler.merchantId);
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check second file

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as an object key

```
class LoginHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.merchantId = '';     
  }

    returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
      this.merchantId = req.params.merchantId;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new LoginHandler

```
class LoginHandler {
    merchantId = "";
  returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
    this.merchantId = req.params.merchantId;
  }
}

module.exports = new LoginHandler();
```

FOR FUTURE REFERENCE (also for myself)

It was confusing to detect what the error was, so for me it was helpful to change the name of the variable:

```
class LoginHandler {
    other= "";
  returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
    other = req.params.merchantId;
  }
}

module.exports = new LoginHandler();
```

Then I saw that the error was `ReferenceError: other is not defined` and could solve it.

Also, besides logging, it was needed to call `returnURLForIframe` to see the error

```
const loginHandler = require("./loginHandler");
class ResponseHandler {
  getResponseFromCOMM(options, token, res) {
    loginHandler.returnURLForIframe({ params: { merchantId: "lalala" } });
    console.log(loginHandler);
  }
}
let rh = new ResponseHandler();
rh.getResponseFromCOMM("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Comment: I updated it with `this.merchantId = req.params.merchantId;`
But I'm getting `Error is  TypeError: Cannot set property 'merchantId' of undefined  at returnURLForIframe (C:\Users\Acer\angularProjects\pamSetup\comm-channel-node-gateway\handler\loginHandler.js:10:23)`

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria this can be related to how you call the function. `loginHandler.returnURLForIframe({ params: { merchantId: "lalala" } });` will work

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/turquoise-spiky-chrysanthemum check this on Glitch.

Comment: Maybe that's another question to ask ;-) Also because you'll have the opportunity to tag `expressJS` and get experts on the matter

Comment: I got this error .. `Error is  TypeError: loginHandler.returnURLForIframe is not a function                                                        at ResponseHandler.getResponseFromCOMM ` Please help me out. Not able to figure the issue. I just want to export the `merchantId` from `loginHandler.js`  to `responseHandler.js`